# Wildcard Arguments in generics

Tags: java, oop, generics

In the program below, how does the step `ob.num.doubleValue()` in `absEqual()` method works? What is it trying to do?

```
class NumericFns<T extends Number>{
     T num;  

     NumericFns(T n ){
         num = n ;
        }

     boolean absEqual(NumericFns<?> ob) {
         if (Math.abs(num.doubleValue())== 
                 Math.abs(ob.num.doubleValue())) 
             return true ;
         return false ;
     }
}
```

---

```
public class demo  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumericFns<Integer> iob = new NumericFns<Integer>(6) ;
        NumericFns<Double> dob = new NumericFns<Double>(-6.0) ;
        if(iob.absEqual(dob))
            System.out.println("Absolute Values are equal") ;
        else
            System.out.println("They differ") ;         
    }    
}
```

Comment: Every `T` of `NumericFns` is at least a `Number`. Without knowing the concrete type, you always know it is at least a `Number`.

Comment: Note that although the title of this question currently refers to Wildcard Arguments, you're not actually using wildcards (`<?>`) in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`ob` is the object you want to compare the current object with.
`ob.num` is the generic of type `T extends Number` that your `NumericFns` class stores.
`ob.num.doubleValue()` just gives you the double value of `ob.num`.

The if statement just takes both double values and checks if they're the same.

Answer (score 0):

Type parameter `T` has an upper bound `Number`, meaning that it is equal to type `T` or a subtype thereof.  Therefore, you can call methods of `Number` on variables of type `T`, such as in this case the method `doubleValue()`.

See [Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html) explanation.

Consequently, this method returns `true` if and only if the double value of both numbers are the same.  This might be the case for an `Integer` value 1 and a `Double` value 1.0.

Note that the method implementation can be simplified to

```
     boolean absEqual(NumericFns<?> ob) {
         return Math.abs(num.doubleValue()) == Math.abs(ob.num.doubleValue()));
     }
```